# interpreting conditions written in natural language into Java code

Tags: java, nlp, interpreter

The problem:

- I want users to be able to write conditions in a simple syntax in a text editor, as in:
  A?outcome1:(B?outcome2:outcome3)

A and B are boolean conditions. So the sentence above means: if A is true, then outcome1, else if B is true, then outcome 2, else outcome3.

In Java, I implement an interpreter of this syntax so that A, B, outcome1, outcome2,outcome3 get translated in values that are pre-stored somewhere (A and B will be functions returning a boolean, outcomes will be objects), and the condition is evaluated and a result is returned.

My question is, am I reinventing the wheel here? Are there Java packages or libraries that already provide neat implementations of "[constrained] natural language interpreted to Java code" kind of functions?

Thx!

Comment: This is not as trivial as one might think. Consider what happens in short-circuiting semantics, for example `(a++ == 0 && b++ == 1) ? foo() : bar()` what if `a != 0`? will `b++` still be invoked? (In java, it won't - but it is not trivial to implement at all)

Comment: sure this is not trivial. I will keep at simple stuffs. For your example, I would simply allow for A?(B?(foo:bar)). To be clear, I am not disputing that the problem can be very complex, I am asking if there are Java libraries that implement it.

Comment: Might be an overkill, but I'd start with [JavaCC](http://javacc.java.net/)

Comment: interesting, thanks! but an overkill indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a class in Java that reads a human-written rule and interprets it. Find it here:
https://github.com/seinecle/Umigon/blob/master/src/java/RuleInterpreter/Interpreter.java